# Is there a standard pythonic way to treat physical units / quantities in python?

Tags: python, physics, units-of-measurement

Is there a standard pythonic way to treat physical units / quantities in python? I saw different module-specific solutions from different fields like physics or neuroscience. But I would rather like to use a standard method than "island"-solutions as others should be able to easily read my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best solution is the [Unum](https://github.com/trzemecki/Unum) package. a de-facto standard, imho.

Answer (score 10):

[quantities](https://github.com/python-quantities/python-quantities) seems to be gaining a lot of traction lately.

Comment: how do you install it using distribute

Comment: The given link is broken
This one seems to work:  https://github.com/python-quantities/python-quantities

Answer (score 4):

There is also [pint](http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/) which in his documentation has a list of other projects in their [faq's](http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/faq.html).

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking at the [Enthought Units module](http://code.enthought.com/projects/files/ETS31_API/enthought.units.html)